# Slideup Box with moving text

Tags: jquery, text, slide

I am looking for a jQuery-function that can do something like that

[image]

I actualy know how to realize the slideshow itself, but don't know a function that can open the boxes like displayed in the screenshot.

The text that is displayed left beside the arrows shoud slide up after clicking on that arrow field, turn bold, and some other content should apear in the now available free space.

Comment: Please look at jQuery `animate`, `slideUp`, `slideToggle` and many other possible alternatives. When you have something implemented, feel free to post specific issues to concrete scenarios. jQuery sliding effects: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/ jQuery effects: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ jQuery UI Demo + documentations: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animate() function with an click event:

```
$('#arrow').click(function(){
     $('div.slidearea').animate({'height':'100px'}); // or how you want it
     $('#thing_to_hide').hide();
     $('thing_to_show').show();
     $('thing_to_get_fat').css({'font-weight':'700'});
});
```

Of course then you need to add the click handler to each slide container, maybe using the each() function...

Comment: Could you show me a example here? 
I just started using jquery 5 days ago :/

Comment: I wont write the full code for you. Put your own code in the question and me or someone might help you debug it!

Comment: I'll try my best tomorrow and insert the code when i am done with it

Answer (score 0):

So that is what I was able to create for now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Animate Test</title>
    <style>
    .animatebox { width: 960px; margin: auto; height: 50px; background: grey; position: absolute; bottom: 250;}
    .hiddenstuff { opacity: 0; } 
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Animate Test</h1>
<button id="animateUP">AnimateUP()</button><button id="animateDOWN">AnimateDOWN()</button>
<div class="animatebox">
<p>Lala Box</p>
<p class="hiddenstuff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmo</p>
</div>


<script>

$("#animateUP").click(function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '400px'
    }, 200 );

});

$("#animateUP").click(function () {
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200 );
});

$("#animateDOWN").click(function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '50px'
    }, 200 );

});

$("#animateDOWN").click(function () {
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '0'
    }, 200 );
});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is exactly what i needed and I am bit proud of it :)
The next thing I wanna to do is to optimize my code, cause I think its not the best way to realize something like that :)

What do I have to do to combine my functions for example:

```
$("#animateUP").click(function () {
    $('.animatebox').animate ({
        height: '400px'
    }, 200 );

});

$("#animateUP").click(function () {
    $('.hiddenstuff').animate ({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200 );
});
```

Sorry for my bad english :-/